# this.state not re-rendering on state change

Tags: spfx-webparts, state

This is a weather widget

1. on default load Hong Kong with lat, long defined
2. Type and Load Google Places Autocomplete API , show list of cities
3. Get City Name and Get Lat Long from Open Cage API
4. Get Lat Long and Get WX from Openweathermap

Problem

- After I type and select City, the getWX() is expected to rerended
- get city, get latlong, get wx conditions, get gmt offset
- update clock2

Which part did I defined incorrectly that lead to no-rendering of the required items ?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './LocationWeatherSidebar.module.scss';
import { ILocationWeatherSidebarProps } from './ILocationWeatherSidebarProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { PageContext } from "@microsoft/sp-page-context";
import { HttpClient, IHttpClientOptions,
   HttpClientResponse, SPHttpClient,
    ISPHttpClientOptions, SPHttpClientResponse,SPHttpClientConfiguration,
    ODataVersion  } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import {
  Environment,
  EnvironmentType
} from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import AnalogClock, { Themes } from 'react-analog-clock';

import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from 'react-google-places-autocomplete';
import 'google';







export interface state{
                isOpen:boolean;
              wxLoc:string;
              wxLoc2:string;
              wxlat:string;
              wxlng:string;
              clock1:Date;
              clock2:Date;
              currDate:Date;
              today:Date;
              wx:any;
              conditions:string;
              temp:any;
              atemp:any;
              gmtoffset:any;
              icon:any;

}



export default class LocationWeatherSidebar extends React.Component<ILocationWeatherSidebarProps,state> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
                 isOpen:false,
              wxLoc:"Hong Kong",
              wxLoc2:"Tokyo ",
              clock1:new Date(),
              currDate:new Date(),
              clock2:null,
              today:null,
              conditions:null,
              wx:null,
              wxlat:"22.302711",
              wxlng:"114.177216",
              temp:null,
              atemp:null,
              gmtoffset:+8,
              icon:null,


     };

    this.showTime=this.showTime.bind(this);
    this.getWx=this.getWx.bind(this);
    this.getUser=this.getUser.bind(this);






    }

    private data:any =[];

    private ppl:any=[];



componentDidMount(){
  var intervalId = setInterval(this.showTime, 1000);
  this.getWx();
  this.getUser();



}

componentDidUpdate(){
  //this.getWx();
}






private showTime(){
  // Creating variables to hold time.
  var date, TimeType, hour, minutes, seconds, fullTime,month,m,day;
  const monthstr=[
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"    ];

  date = new Date();
  hour = date.getHours();
  m= date.getMonth();
  month=monthstr[m];
  day  = date.getDate(); // getDay= week of the day 0=sunday , Date as actual date.


       if(hour <= 11){
    TimeType = 'AM';
       }else{
    TimeType = 'PM';
       }


       if( hour > 12 ) {
          hour = hour - 12;
       }

       if( hour == 0 ){
           hour = 12;
        }
   minutes = date.getMinutes();

      if(minutes < 10){
             minutes = '0' + minutes.toString();
      }
  seconds = date.getSeconds();
   if(seconds < 10){
    seconds = '0' + seconds.toString();
       }
  // Adding all the variables in fullTime variable.
  fullTime =month+"  "+day+",  "+ hour.toString() + ':' + minutes.toString() + ':' + seconds.toString() + ' ' + TimeType.toString();

  this.setState({
    today: fullTime,

    });
}




private async getWx(){
  const opencage=`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${this.state.wxLoc}&key=k&pretty=1`;
  const res = await fetch(opencage);
  let data = await res.json();
  var lat=data.results[0].geometry.lat;
  var lng=data.results[0].geometry.lng;
  var city=data.results[0].components.city;
  this.setState({wxlat:lat});
  this.setState({wxlng:lng});
  this.setState({wxLoc:city});

 const openwxmap=`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${this.state.wxlat}&lon=${this.state.wxlng}&appid=key&units=metric`;
 const res2 = await  fetch(openwxmap);
 let data2 =  await res2.json();
 var feels_like=data2.list[0].main.feels_like;
 feels_like= feels_like.toFixed(1);
 var temp=data2.list[0].main.temp;
 temp=temp.toFixed(1);
 var conditions=data2.list[0].weather[0].description;
 var timezone=data2.city.timezone;
 timezone=timezone/60/60;
 var icon=data2.list[0].weather[0].icon;

 var icon_url=`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}@2x.png`;

 this.setState({

             temp:temp,
             atemp:feels_like,
             conditions:conditions,
             gmtoffset:timezone,
             icon:icon_url
            });

debugger;


  }

private  getUser() {
 var qurl;



qurl="/_api/search/query?querytext='@ABC'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=60&$top=3";
const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = { headers: {
  Accept: "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;charset=utf-8"
 }};
    let config: SPHttpClientConfiguration = new SPHttpClientConfiguration({
  defaultODataVersion: ODataVersion.v3
    });
this.props.SPHttpClient.get(this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl + qurl,config ,opt).then((response) => {
    response.json().then(res => {
      let result=[];
     result=res.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;


            for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            this.ppl.push({
               name:result[i].Cells[14].Value,//Preferred name
               jobtitle:result[i].Cells[8].Value,//jobtitle
              workemail:result[i].Cells[21].Value,//workemail
               avatar:result[i].Cells[13].Value,//picture url
               });

          this.forceUpdate();
          }
      });
   });




}




  public render(): React.ReactElement<ILocationWeatherSidebarProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.locationWeatherSidebar }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
            <div className={styles.panel}>
                <div className={styles.title}>
                   TODAY
                   </div>
                       <div className={styles.ddate}>
                            {this.state.today}
                      </div>
                      <hr/>
               <div className={styles.wx}>

               <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      onSelect={({ description }) => (
        this.setState({ wxLoc: description })
              )}

      placeholder={this.state.wxLoc}
    />    {this.state.wxlat}                 
                <div className={styles.wx}>
                    <div className={styles.icon}>
                       <img src={this.state.icon} />

                    </div>
                  <div className={styles.currtemp}>
                        {this.state.temp}‎°
                     </div>
                  <div className={styles.currcond}>
                               {this.state.conditions}
                    </div>
                  <div className={styles.temp}>
                     {this.state.atemp}°
                      <img src="https://1.sharepoint.com/s/Shared%20Documents/temp_logo.png"/>
                       {this.state.temp}‎°
                  </div>
                </div>

                </div>
               <hr/>
               <div className={styles.time}>
                            <AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} /><br/>
                              Hong Kong<br/><br/>
                            <AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} gmtOffset={this.state.gmtoffset}  /><br/>
                             {this.state.wxLoc} <br/>
                 </div>
              <hr/>


            <div className={styles.newjoiner}>
            New Joiner
                  {this.ppl.map((data)=>

               <div className={styles.text}>

               <h1> <img src={data.avatar} width= "40px" height="40px"/></h1>
                <p>{data.name}</p>
                <p>{data.jobtitle}</p>

                </div>


                )}

             </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Previous Design

[image: Previous wx part]

Current Web part

[image: Current Webpart]

You see the weather part is empty, as I have reached the quota of all three API request call of the day

from 2020-02-21

- Upon user input city
- Get City name, City ID, City Wx, City Timezone
- show Wx
- Update Clock2, 1st load +8 by componentDidmount(), 2nd load invoke after this.state.gmtOffset has changed

Problem:

- clock2 not re-rendering after input new city, new timezone fetched

```
private showClock2(offset="+8") {
  offset=this.state.gmtoffset;

 ReactDOM.render(<AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} gmtOffset={offset} />,
   document.getElementById('root'));

debugger;
```

From private getWx()

```
this.setState({
  wxlat:data.city.cityLatitude,
  wxlng:data.city.cityLongitude,
  wxLoc:data.city.cityName,
  conditions:data.city.forecast.forecastDay[0].weather,
  temp:data.city.forecast.forecastDay[0].minTemp,
  atemp:data.city.forecast.forecastDay[0].maxTemp,
  gmtoffset:timezone,
  icon:iconurl,

});
debugger;

this.showClock2(this.state.gmtoffset);

debugger;
```

Solutions  -- 2020-02-21 1744

- Unmountcomponentatnode
- Render component
- this.forceUpdate()

Example

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root')); 
   const element =(<AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} gmtOffset={offset} />);
   ReactDOM.render(element,
     document.getElementById('root'));
     console.log("showClock2");
     this.forceUpdate();
```

Comment: I think you need to name your state interface something other than `state`.  It may be conflicting with React's `this.state`.  Try changing your interface to something like `export interface ILocationWeatherSidebarState { `, and then you would need to update your class declaration to `export default class LocationWeatherSidebar extends React.Component<ILocationWeatherSidebarProps, ILocationWeatherSidebarState> { `

Comment: thanks for reply, i changed the name but seems nothing changed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getWX()` is not called when you are changing the city, you are calling `setState` for `'wxLoc'`.

This will not trigger an update of the whole component. I see you have `this.getWx()` in `componentDidMount`, but this only runs when the component first is mounted (on page refresh).

I would rewrite the getWX method to take an input parameter and use that instead of the state value when doing your API calls:

```
private async getWX(wxLoc?: string) {
    const opencage=`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${wxLoc}&key=k&pretty=1`;

    ...
    ...
```

You should also try to minimize the number of setState calls in the method:

```
this.setState({wxlat:lat});
this.setState({wxlng:lng});
this.setState({wxLoc:city});
```

to:

```
this.setState({wxlat:lat, wxlng: lng, wxLoc: city });
```

Comment: It works !! thanks

Comment: I am trying to re-render the clock after input city name and get WX, I attempted ReactDom.render, it gets the updated timezone but it won't re-render why is that ? I have updated the question

Comment: That will depend on how the clock component handles property updates (as the offset is a property to that) - maybe it only updates when another property changes?

Comment: I attempted this code below unmountcomponent, render a component and this.forceUpdate(), It worked but seems not recommened?
`ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root')); 
   const element =(<AnalogClock theme={Themes.light} width={120} gmtOffset={offset} />);
   ReactDOM.render(element,
     document.getElementById('root'));
     console.log("showClock2");
     this.forceUpdate();`

i wonder if there is a better way :)

Comment: Try this: in your AnalogClock component, add key={this.state.gmtoffset}. This should force the component to update whenever gmtoffset changes. You should not need other methods to update this, the state change itself should be enough.